Samba not functioning after computer restart
I've recently tried to set up a samba share on my computer for my local network, however I've run into the issue where samba decides that it will no longer work once i restart my computer. Sometimes it will come back up after about an hour of uninstalling and reinstalling it but that is not always the case. I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04.6 on the computer hosting the share, however I have also run into this issue when using Mint in the past.
